# C - index applied to pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I want to ask what does C do when it sees an index on a pointer to pointer; for example:

```
struct X {
  int a;
  int b;
};

struct X ** ptr;
```

What will happen if a statement contains :

```
ptr[i] // where i is an unsigned int
```

Comment: Please open a new question for the second issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19043766/682869

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any pointer can be used with array indexing, so `ptr[i]` will be a pointer to `struct X`.

However, you have to allocate memory for `ptr` first of course, otherwise you will dereference an uninitialized pointer leading to undefined behavior. And if you dereference `ptr[i]` without initializing that pointer, then you're again have undefined behavior.

Comment: @kenny Which is what I wrote.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : in your answer, is it struct X or struct X * ?

Comment: @Jake Like I said, "`ptr[i]` will be a **pointer** to `struct X`", in other words `ptr[i]` is of type `struct X *`.

Comment: @Jake No no no... Please don't do that. Now it's a completely different question compared to the original. Please post that as a separate question instead.

Answer (score 1):

It returns a garbage value. Since "ptr" is a pointer to a pointer. You haven't declared what it's actually pointing to. For example..

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct X {
  int a;
  int b;
};
int main()
{
struct X ** ptr;

unsigned int i=1;
printf("%d",ptr[i]);
return 0;
}
```

I got the output.

```
1483736418
```

which is a garbage value of a pointer that I haven't defined.

Answer (score 0):

the pointer is only derefernced only once. This means the type of the expression is `struct X *`.
You now have a 1D pointer array to all pointer with the a particuar row of your first 2D array.

Comment: Don't mix dimensions and arrays in. They're not relevant. We're dealing with pointers here, not with arrays.

Comment: but he is using the pointer like an array. Also you can write a `a[x]` to an `*(a + x)`. This means you can use even a single pointer like a array with only one element.

Comment: @kenny "...you can use even a single pointer like a array with only one element..." this is imprecise at best. As you correctly point out, `a[x]` is equivalent to `*(a+x)`, but this has nothing to do with the existence of any element of an array. Using a pointer with array syntax does not create an array out of nowhere. There is no allocation, so there are no elements.

Comment: I did not say that this will create an array only that you interpret it logical like an 2d array. Also this is not the complete code so you can not say if its allocated or not.

Comment: @kenny No, he's not "using the pointer like an array". The `[]` operator has two separate meanings: pointer dereferencing and array access. Here it is used to dereference a pointer. Also, at best, a pointer-to-pointer can be thought of as a pointer to the first element of a sparse array, but never as a 2D array. A 2D aray looks like this: `T arr[n_rows][n_cols]`