# C - index on pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers

If I have:

```
struct X {
  int a;
  struct X* next;
}

struct X** ptr;
```

ptr is initialized with the address of a struct X, and each struct X 's 
next points to another struct X. What will one get by using

```
ptr[i] // where i is unsigned int
```

**Here is the source of my question** : (it's link to code from selinux) : [code](http://userspace.selinuxproject.org/trac/browser/libselinux/src/avc_sidtab.c#L68)

The types are defined in : [types](http://userspace.selinuxproject.org/trac/browser/libselinux/src/avc_sidtab.h#L22)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - index applied to pointer to pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043395/c-index-applied-to-pointer-to-pointer)

Comment: waight, what exactly are you asking? how to acces next? Or is your question realy just what `ptr[i]`'s execution value would be?

Comment: and what exactly in the code fits your sample code? I wasn't able to find it

Answer (score 0):

You will get garbage. For the pointer arithmetic in `p[i]` to work you need to have the objects (in this case the pointers-to-struct) one after the other in the memory (in an array).

In your case you need to follow the `next` pointer `i` times.

```
struct X *p = *ptr;
for (j = 0; j < i; ++j) p = p->next;
/* now p points to the i-th struct */
```

If the structs are in fact in an array, this is equivalent to

```
struct X *p = (*ptr)[i];
```

But in that case, the `next` would be useless.

Comment: In that code, the `htable` is indeed an array of pointers. It is allocated in line 35.

Answer (score -1):

`ptr[i]` will point to the `i`th pointer of `ptr`. Which is assuming that `ptr` has a row of `i` pointers, which are assumed to be pointing to elements of type `X`.

Comment: Dear downvoter.... please explain me why you voted down. From my point of view it is absolutly correct what I said. So if there are any wrong statements please explain it me( or any one else) what is incorrect, as I would like to improve my knowledge. (Porbably thats why we all are here)